# Boxplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I would like to change the quantiles in the boxplot, so that the upper whisker is 95th percentile, and the lower whisker is 5th percentile. I tried the following code (see below) but it doesn't adjust the outliers.

```
boxplot(x);
p = prctile(x,[5 95]);

% Replace upper end y value of whisker
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Whisker'));
for j=1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(2) = p(2,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% Replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Upper Adjacent Value'));
for j=1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(:) = p(2,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% Replace lower end y value of whisker
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Whisker'));
for j=1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(1) = p(1,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end

% Replace all y values of adjacent value
h = flipud(findobj(gca,'Tag','Lower Adjacent Value'));
for j=1:length(h);
    ydata = get(h(j),'YData');
    ydata(:) = p(1,j);
    set(h(j),'YData',ydata);
end
```

Comment: You could take any boxplot code from FEX (for example [mine](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51134-boxplot)) and modify it to compute different percentiles.